# Facing "card required" error while integrating Stripe payment gateway in angular 6

Tags: typescript, angular6, stripe-payments

Here I am trying to integrate stripe payment gateway in angular with .net core.
below is my integration part.
Adding below script related code change to my index.html file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    Stripe.setPublishableKey('pk_test_o8SJmIFp8LKkBw9WAmjn8Al9');
  </script>
```

My component.html file.

```
<form [formGroup]="paymentForm" (ngSubmit)="purchaseTicket()" #formDir="ngForm">
    <span class="payment-message">{{message}}</span>
    <div class="form-row">
      <label>
        <span>Card Number</span>
        <input formControlName="cardNumber" name="card-number" type="text" size="20" data-stripe="number">
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <label>
        <span>Expiration (MM/YY)</span>
        <input formControlName="expiryMonth" name="expiry-month" type="text" size="2" data-stripe="exp_month">
      </label>
      <span> / </span>
      <input formControlName="expiryYear" name="expiry-year" type="text" size="2" data-stripe="exp_year">
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <label>
        <span>CVC</span>
        <input formControlName="cvc" name="cvc" type="text" size="4" data-stripe="cvc">
      </label>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Payment">
  </form>
```

component.ts code is as below.

```
loginForm: FormGroup;
 myAppUrl: string = "";
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder,private _zone: NgZone, private _http: Http){
    this.myAppUrl = "https://localhost:44303/";
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      cardNumber: [null,],
      expiryMonth: [null,],
      expiryYear: [null,],
      cvc:[null,]

    });

 }

  public model: any;
  public card: any;
  public errorMessage: string;
  public successMessage: string;
  cardNumber: string;
  expiryMonth: string;
  expiryYear: string;
  cvc: string;
  message: string;

  purchaseTicket() {
    console.log("clicked");
    (<any>window).Stripe.card.createToken(
      this.card,
      (status: number, response: any) => {
        if (status === 200) {
          this.model.token = response.id;
          this._http
            .get(this.myAppUrl + 'api/stripe/Pay')
            .subscribe(
              result => {
                this.successMessage = 'Thank you for purchasing a ticket!';
                console.log(this.successMessage);
              },
              error => {
                this.errorMessage = 'There was a problem registering you.';
                console.error(error);
              }
            );
        } else {
          this.errorMessage = 'There was a problem purchasing the ticket.';
          console.error(response.error.message);
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

and now when i am executing this code then it gives me the error as **"ERROR Error: card required"** which is the variable declared inside my component class. As i have tried to assigned card number to the same variable but still it is showing the same error.

[This is the artcile which i have followed](https://blog.mgechev.com/2016/07/05/using-stripe-payment-with-angular-2/)

Comment: Try passing the card as object {
      number: this.cardNumber,
      exp_month: this.expiryMonth,
      exp_year: this.expiryYear,
      cvc: this.cvc
    }
as https://blog.mgechev.com/2016/07/05/using-stripe-payment-with-angular-2/ has suggested

Comment: Thanx wsw that was realy helpfull.